# How do I remove a simple piece of software?

Tags: fedora, yum, gnome3

I want to get rid of the automatically installed solitaire "games" in my brand new Fedora 18. I tried [the gnome way](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/User_Guide/chap-User_Guide-Managing_software.html#sect-User_Guide-Using_PackageKit-Removing_software), but nothing gets listed when I search for "silitaire". I tried the command line way:

> $ su -c 'yum remove *solitaire'
>   Password:
>   Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
>   No Match for argument: *solitaire
>   No Packages marked for removal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you are looking for is `/usr/bin/sol`, part of package aisleriot. In any case, you should be able to:

```
yum erase /usr/bin/sol
```

(`yum` understands package names, file names and features provided; and also handles groups of packages).

Comment: Thanks, that worked AND it removed the annoying "Games" submenu. However, I would appreciate ideas on how would have I been able to track the package myself.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. With `rpm -qf /the/file/of/interest` you get the RPM package to which it belongs, if any.

Answer (score 1):

To find the mapping from a desktop file entry to a program/package, is kind of magic from the yum POV. In theory you might expect to be able to do:

yum search solitaire

...and it will show either gnome-games or aisleriot as a package, however at least the gnome-games package doesn't show up here.

You can use google, "gnome solitare" will give you the aisleriot and gnome-games pages as the first two hits ... and the former does explicitly mention it is known as "sol" as well.

If you know that desktop files are in /usr/share/applications you can do:

```
% fgrep -i solitaire /usr/share/applications/*
```

...and that will tell you the filename which you can use "yum provides" on (or on the command name without that file).
Or you can do it the graphical way:

1. open the menu editor (alacarte -- can be found by "yum search menu editor")
2. Find menu entry you want to delete.
3. Look in properties for command name.
4. yum provides sol